# Select the first record after the last but one X

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the first `BEG_PERIOD` date immediately after the last but one record of X (`DEF_ENDING`) of each user (`USER_ID`).

So I have this:

| USER_ID | BEG_PERIOD | END_PERIOD | DEF_ENDING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | 01-07-2022 | 31-07-2022 | X |
| 159 | 25-09-2022 | 15-10-2022 | X |
| 159 | 01-11-2022 | 13-11-2022 |  |
| 159 | 14-11-2022 | 21-12-2022 | X |
| 159 | 01-01-2023 | 30-01-2023 | X |
| 414 | 01-04-2022 | 31-05-2022 | X |
| 414 | 01-07-2022 | 30-09-2022 |  |
| 414 | 01-10-2022 | 01-12-2022 | X |
| 480 | 01-07-2022 | 30-06-2022 |  |
| 480 | 01-07-2022 | 30-08-2022 | X |
| 480 | 02-09-2022 | 01-11-2022 | X |
| 503 | 15-03-2022 | 16-06-2022 | X |
| 503 | 19-07-2022 | 23-07-2022 |  |
| 503 | 24-07-2022 | 31-10-2022 |  |
| 503 | 01-11-2022 | 21-12-2022 | X |

The dates I need are the ones in bold

Can you help me?

I tried this but I only get the latest dates :(

```
SELECT
    p.USER_ID,
    p.BEG_PERIOD
FROM
    PERIODS p
    INNER JOIN PERIODS p2 ON
        p.USER_ID = p2.USER_ID
        AND
        p.BEG_PERIOD = (
            SELECT
                MAX( BEG_PERIOD )
            FROM
                PERIODS
            WHERE
                PERIODS.USER_ID = p.USER_ID
        )
WHERE
    p.USER_ID > 10
```

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I try in SQL server 2008, it's school server

Comment: I don't understand by what rule you pick the dates. Twice it's the last row, once the penultimate, once the antepenultimate. Twice it's an X row, twice a non-X row. I don't see the pattern.

Comment: soo... the problem: users work for periods of time... (could be days or weeks). Sometimes they leave school but not permanently, at other times the departure is permanent... (they cease the employment relationship), but they can return to school again, so it is the first date that is necessary after the last but one departure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work based on the sample data:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        sum(case when DEF_ENDING = 'X' then 1 end)
            over (partition by USER_ID order by BEG_PERIOD desc) as grp
    from PERIODS
)
select
    USER_ID,
    min(BEG_PERIOD) as BEG_PERIOD,
    min(END_PERIOD) as END_PERIOD,
    min(DEF_ENDING) as DEF_ENDING
from data
where grp = 1
group by USER_ID;
```

If you can't rely on the two dates being minimums then:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        sum(case when DEF_ENDING = 'X' then 1 end)
            over (partition by USER_ID order by BEG_PERIOD desc) as grp
    from PERIODS
), data2 as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by USER_ID order by BEG_PERIOD) as rn
    from data
    where grp = 1
)
select *
from data2
where rn = 1;
```

This can also be done entirely via subqueries if that's more appropriate at the level of your class:

```
select USER_ID, min(BEG_PERIOD), min(END_PERIOD), min(DEF_ENDING)
from periods p1
where p1.BEG_PERIOD > (
    select max(BEG_PERIOD)
    from periods p2
    where p2.USER_ID = p1.USER_ID and p2.DEF_ENDING = 'X'
        and exists (
            select 1
            from periods p3
            where p3.USER_ID = p2.USER_ID and p3.DEF_ENDING = 'X'
                and p3.BEG_PERIOD > p2.BEG_PERIOD
        )
    )
group by USER_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for listening.
In both results it gives the same error:

"The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled."

Comment: See if my `group by` fixed it.

Comment: No, it gives the same error.

Comment: Did you try both queries? That message seems to be a bug in 2008.

Comment: @tg_rs Note that I had inserted the `group by` in the wrong place earlier. Here's a link to a fiddle that works: https://dbfiddle.uk/jVSdoMHt For some reason SQL Server seems to be down at the moment but you shouldn't have any issues if you switch to that once it comes up again.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/AgwmnIB8

Comment: That's it!! With 'exists' it works perfectly. Thank you very much @shawnt00

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using the `ROW_NUMBER` and `LAG' window functions:

```
/* this to assign row numbers only for rows where def_ending = 'X' */
with order_def_ending as 
(
  select *,
   case def_ending when 'X' then
    row_number() over (partition by user_id order by 
                        case def_ending when 'X' then 1 else 2 end, 
                        end_period desc)
    else null end rn,
    lag(def_ending, 1, def_ending) over (partition by user_id order by end_period) pde /* previous end_period value */
  from yourTbl
),
lag_rn as
(
  select *, 
    lag(rn) over (partition by user_id order by end_period) prn /* previous row_number value */
  from order_def_ending
)
select user_id, beg_period, end_period, def_ending
from lag_rn
where (
        prn = 2 or /* when there are multiple rows with def_ending = 'X' */
        (prn = 1 and rn is null) /* when there is only one row with def_ending = 'X' */
      ) and pde = 'X' /* ensure that the previous value of def_ending is = 'X' */
order by user_id, end_period
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EA55dU5E)

Comment: thanks for your time. Result: "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled."

Comment: I created the ROW_NUMBER but it's possible to get the correct date without 'LAG'?

Comment: As I remember, LAG is supported since SQL Server 2012, anyway, there could be a workaround to simulate the LAG, I will try to provide you with it.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is not supported anymore, it's time to upgrade :)

Comment: I know. And I think the teacher knows too :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think, this works on SQL server 2008

```
with periods as(
select USER_ID, cast(BEG_PERIOD as date)BEG_PERIOD,cast(END_PERIOD as date)END_PERIOD,DEF_ENDING
from (values
 (159,'01-07-2022','31-07-2022','X')
,(159,'25-09-2022','15-10-2022','X')
,(159,'01-11-2022','13-11-2022',null)
,(159,'14-11-2022','21-12-2022','X')
,(159,'01-01-2023','30-01-2023','X')
,(414,'01-04-2022','31-05-2022','X')
,(414,'01-07-2022','30-09-2022',null)
,(414,'01-10-2022','01-12-2022','X')
,(480,'01-07-2022','30-06-2022',null)
,(480,'01-07-2022','30-08-2022','X')
,(480,'02-09-2022','01-11-2022','X')
,(503,'15-03-2022','16-06-2022','X')
,(503,'19-07-2022','23-07-2022',null)
,(503,'24-07-2022','31-10-2022',null)
,(503,'01-11-2022','21-12-2022','X')
)t(USER_ID, BEG_PERIOD, END_PERIOD, DEF_ENDING)
)
,cte as (
select * 
   ,(select sum(case when def_ending='X' then 1 else 0 end) 
     from periods t2 where t2.user_id=t1.USER_ID and t2.BEG_PERIOD>=t1.BEG_PERIOD
    ) N -- last but one has N=2, all next N=1 (reverse order of counts)
from periods t1
)
select * 
   ,(select min(t2.BEG_PERIOD) 
     from cte t2 where t2.user_id=t1.USER_ID and t2.N=1
    ) LastButOne  -- first after last but one with N=1
from cte t1
```

Result

| USER_ID | BEG_PERIOD | END_PERIOD | DEF_ENDING | N | LastButOne |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-07-31 | X | 4 | 2023-01-01 |
| 159 | 2022-09-25 | 2022-10-15 | X | 3 | 2023-01-01 |
| 159 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-11-13 | NULL | 2 | 2023-01-01 |
| 159 | 2022-11-14 | 2022-12-21 | X | 2 | 2023-01-01 |
| 159 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-30 | X | 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 414 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-31 | X | 2 | 2022-07-01 |
| 414 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-09-30 | NULL | 1 | 2022-07-01 |
| 414 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-01 | X | 1 | 2022-07-01 |
| 480 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-06-30 | NULL | 2 | 2022-09-02 |
| 480 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-08-30 | X | 2 | 2022-09-02 |
| 480 | 2022-09-02 | 2022-11-01 | X | 1 | 2022-09-02 |
| 503 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-06-16 | X | 2 | 2022-07-19 |
| 503 | 2022-07-19 | 2022-07-23 | NULL | 1 | 2022-07-19 |
| 503 | 2022-07-24 | 2022-10-31 | NULL | 1 | 2022-07-19 |
| 503 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-12-21 | X | 1 | 2022-07-19 |

About Parallel Data Warehouse,
as mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47116/in-microsoft-sql-server-2008-syntax-generates-the-error-the-parallel-data-ware), Non-PDW versions of SQL Server before 2012 do not support the ORDER BY clause with aggregate functions like MIN.
Windowing function support was considerably extended in 2012, compared with the basic implementation available starting with SQL Server 2005. The extensions were made available in Parallel Data Warehouse before being incorporated in the box product.

Comment: This one also fits v 2008 version. Thank you very much :)